# Login using google with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, google-signin

I am building an admin panel with codeIgniter and I want Google sign in to be used for logging into it. I have tried the technique showed in Codexworld.com but after redirecting its is showing page not found, even though the controller and functions are all there. Really need a help have been stuck up with this from a long time now.

I don't understand where the code is going wrong.

My Controller

---

```
public function authGoogle()
        {
            $this->load->helper('url');
             $this->load->library('google');



        //google login url
        $data['loginURL'] = $this->google->loginURL();

        //load google login view
        $this->load->view('login',$data);
    }

    public function profile(){
        //redirect to login page if user not logged in
        if(!$this->session->userdata('loggedIn')){
//            redirect('/user_authentication/');
        }

        //get user info from session
//        $data['userData'] = $this->session->userdata('userData');

        //load user profile view
//        $this->load->view('user_authentication/profile',$data);
    }

    public function auth_user()
    {
//        echo "This is working";    


        $this->load->helper('url');

        if($this->session->userdata('loggedIn') == true)
        {
            echo 'this is working';
        }

        if(isset($_GET['code']))
        {

            $this->load->library('google');
            //authenticate user
            $this->google->getAuthenticate();

            //get user info from google
            $gpInfo = $this->google->getUserInfo();

            //preparing data for database insertion
            $userData['oauth_provider'] = 'google';
            $userData['oauth_uid']      = $gpInfo['id'];
            $userData['first_name']     = $gpInfo['given_name'];
            $userData['last_name']      = $gpInfo['family_name'];
            $userData['email']          = $gpInfo['email'];
            $userData['gender']         = !empty($gpInfo['gender'])?$gpInfo['gender']:'';
            $userData['locale']         = !empty($gpInfo['locale'])?$gpInfo['locale']:'';
            $userData['profile_url']    = !empty($gpInfo['link'])?$gpInfo['link']:'';
            $userData['picture_url']    = !empty($gpInfo['picture'])?$gpInfo['picture']:'';

            //insert or update user data to the database
            $this->load->model('Usermodel');
            $userID = $this->Usermodel->checkUser($userData);

            //store status & user info in session
            $this->session->set_userdata('loggedIn', true);
            $this->session->set_userdata('userData', $userData);

            //redirect to profile page
            echo "This is working";  
        } 
    }


    public function logout(){
        $this->load->helper('url');
        //delete login status & user info from session
        $this->session->unset_userdata('loggedIn');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('userData');
        $this->session->sess_destroy();

        //redirect to login page
//        redirect('/Welcome/authGoogle');
    }
```

My Modal

---

```
public function checkUser($data = array()){

        $this->tableName = 'users';
        $this->primaryKey = 'id';

        $this->db->select($this->primaryKey);
        $this->db->from($this->tableName);
        $this->db->where(array('oauth_provider'=>$data['oauth_provider'],'oauth_uid'=>$data['oauth_uid']));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $check = $query->num_rows();

        if($check > 0){
            $result = $query->row_array();
            $data['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $update = $this->db->update($this->tableName,$data,array('id'=>$result['id']));
            $userID = $result['id'];
        }else{
            $data['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $data['modified']= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $insert = $this->db->insert($this->tableName,$data);
            $userID = $this->db->insert_id();
        }

        return $userID?$userID:false;
    }
```

My Google configuration

---

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Google API Configuration
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  client_id         string   Your Google API Client ID.
|  client_secret     string   Your Google API Client secret.
|  redirect_uri      string   URL to redirect back to after login.
|  application_name  string   Your Google application name.
|  api_key           string   Developer key.
|  scopes            string   Specify scopes
*/
$config['google']['client_id']        = 'XXXX';
$config['google']['client_secret']    = 'XXX';
$config['google']['redirect_uri']     = 'XXX';
$config['google']['application_name'] = 'XXX';
$config['google']['api_key']          = '';
$config['google']['scopes']           = array();
?>
```

My google oauth library

---

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Google{

    public function __construct(){

        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->config->load('google');

        require_once APPPATH .'libraries/gplus/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/autoload.php';
        require APPPATH .'libraries/gplus/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php';
        require APPPATH .'libraries/gplus/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Oauth2.php';

        $this->client = new Google_Client();
        $this->client->setApplicationName($CI->config->item('application_name', 'google'));
        $this->client->setClientId($CI->config->item('client_id', 'google'));
        $this->client->setClientSecret($CI->config->item('client_secret', 'google'));
        $this->client->setRedirectUri($CI->config->item('redirect_uri', 'google'));
        $this->client->setDeveloperKey($CI->config->item('api_key', 'google'));
        $this->client->setScopes($CI->config->item('scopes', 'google'));
        $this->client->setAccessType('online');
        $this->client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
        $this->client->setScopes('email');
        $this->oauth2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($this->client);
    }

    public function loginURL() {
        return $this->client->createAuthUrl();
    }

    public function getAuthenticate() {
        return $this->client->authenticate();
    }

    public function getAccessToken() {
        return $this->client->getAccessToken();
    }

    public function setAccessToken() {
        return $this->client->setAccessToken();
    }

    public function revokeToken() {
        return $this->client->revokeToken();
    }

    public function getUserInfo() {
        return $this->oauth2->userinfo->get();
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: What redirect are you talking about? Can you explain it a bit? You have simply pasted all the code from CodexWorld without going into detail of what problem you are facing.